# How to show values from list of dictionaries in QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Good time everyone.
I'm trying to populate QTableWidget with values from list of dictionaries.
But in table shown only values from last dictionary.
Looks like previous values rewriting on every loop.
How to make it right? Please, help!

```py
spisok = [{'some': 'any 1',
          'some2': 'any 2',
          'some3': 'any 3'},
          {'some': 'any 1a',
           'some2': 'any 2a',
           'some3': 'any 3a'},
          {'some': 'any 1b',
           'some2': 'any 2b',
           'some3': 'any 3b'}
          ]        

for item_list in spisok:
    for col, key in enumerate(item_list):
        for row, value in enumerate(item_list):
            newitem = QTableWidgetItem(value)
            table.setItem(row, col, newitem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    row_count = (len(spisok))
    column_count = (len(spisok[0]))

    table.setColumnCount(column_count) 
    table.setRowCount(row_count)

    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels((list(spisok[0].keys())))

    for row in range(row_count):  # add items from array to QTableWidget
        for column in range(column_count):
            item = (list(spisok[row].values())[column])
            table.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(item))
```

Result:

[image]

Example:

```
spisok = [{'some': 'any 1',
           'some2': 'any 2',
           'some3': 'any 3'},
          {'some': 'any 1a',
           'some2': 'any 2a',
           'some3': 'any 3a'},
          {'some': 'any 1b',
           'some2': 'any 2b',
           'some3': 'any 3b'},
          {'some': 'any 1c',
           'some2': 'any 2c',
           'some3': 'any 3c'},
          {'some': 'any 1d',
           'some2': 'any 2d',
           'some3': 'any 3d'}
          ]
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class TableWidget(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        spisok = [{'some': 'any 1',  'some2': 'any 2',  'some3': 'any 3'},
                  {'some': 'any 1a', 'some2': 'any 2a', 'some3': 'any 3a'},
                  {'some': 'any 1b', 'some2': 'any 2b', 'some3': 'any 3b'}
                 ]   

        table = QTableWidget()
        table.setRowCount(3)
        table.setColumnCount(3)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(table)

        for row, item_list in enumerate(spisok):
            for col, key in enumerate(item_list):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item_list[key])
                table.setItem(row, col, newitem)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TableWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]